# View votes on Comments in Activity

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity, comment-voting

At times I have upvoted comments because the comment had a useful tip or pointer. If I want to later reference that point, however, there is no easy way to find the comment I voted on. I am suggesting that users should be able so see a list of all comments they voted on, just like they see a list of all questions/answers voted on.

As shown in the picture below, comments can be added as just another filter for votes:

[image]

Comment: \*insert tedious "comments are second-class citizens" speech here*

Comment: @NathanTuggy Second-class still should not equal disappearance into oblivion.

Comment: That's why I said it's *tedious*.

Comment: It's 2018 and I want this. Every comment even has a permalink to make this possible. Is it (or can it be) possible to do this via a SEDE query at least? Please?

Comment: Also, is the recommendation to work around this _really_ to maintain a hand-kept list of comment permalinks somewhere?