# Where to see my votes on comment

Tags: support, comments, voting

I am trying to see history of the votes I cast on comments.

Where can I see those?

Comment: Related feature request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268264/view-votes-on-comments-in-activity.

Comment: thanx  Sha Wiz Dow Ard for the link. hope developers of this site will pay attention to this desired feature

Comment: Very very slim chances, comments are not really important.

Answer (score 9):

**You cannot**

There are only 2 tabs where you can see your activity history [`all actions` tab] and voting history [`Votes` tab].

Both of them do not show comment votes in them.

Comment: I don't know much about queries, but is it possible to make a query for this?

Comment: @Unitato no, SEDE does not expose voting history of any kind. (Except total number of votes, without telling who voted.)

Comment: thanx Dawny33 i am upvoting you for the clear-cut answer. i'll leave it as an open item pending future enhancement by the developers of this site